# Cannot invoke 'swapAt' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'

Tags: swift

Please consider following:

```
extension MutableCollection where Self:BidirectionalCollection, Element: Equatable {

    mutating func moveRight(_ value: Element){

        for i in (0..<self.count) {

            if (self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)] == value){
                swapAt(0, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode show me error at `swapAt(0,5)`. Why? `swapAt` is method that require 2 integers (indexes), and i provide 2 integer values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no, [MutableCollection.swapAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/3018230-swapat) is not defined to take two `Int`, it is defined in terms of `Index` of the `MutableCollection`:

```
swapAt(Self.Index, Self.Index)
```

Therefore you cannot just use `Int` unless you add

```
Index == Int
```

constraint to your declaration, making it:

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection, Element: Equatable, Index == Int {
    mutating func moveRight(_ value: Element){
        for i in (0..<self.count) {
            if (self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)] == value){
                swapAt(0, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to limit yourself to integer indices, you should start by replacing iteration from `0 ..< count` by iteration over indices:

```
for i in indices {
    if (self[i] == value) {
       // do swap
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, well, please take a look at my updated question. Why such miss leading occured?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You are looking at `Array`, not at `MutableCollection`. Array has `Index == Int` therefore `swapAt` on `Array` is defined using `Int`. This would work if you were extending `Array` directly.

Comment: If OP doesn't need to access the collection reversed and or the collection's last property, the constraint to BidirectionalCollection is pointless here.

Answer (score 1):

The screen capture is that of `swapAt` for `Array`, not `MutableCollection`. Unlike arrays, collections may have non-integer [index](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/3018230-swapat) (like String).

You could use `Self.Index` this way:

```
extension MutableCollection where Self:BidirectionalCollection, Element: Equatable {
    mutating func moveRight(_ value: Element){
        for i in (0..<self.count) {
            if self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)] == value {
                swapAt(startIndex, index(startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or as suggested in the comments by **Sulthan** and **Leo Dabus** :

```
extension MutableCollection where Self: BidirectionalCollection, Element: Equatable {
    mutating func moveRight(_ value: Element) {
        for i in indices where self[i] == value {
            swapAt(startIndex, index(startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, probably we should iterate over `indices` in the first place :)